# Gmail API (Python) - Unable to add a reply to the thread

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I want to add a reply to a gmail thread via the API.

[Google says to](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads):

> simply add a threadId key paired with a thread ID to a message's metadata, the message object.

And here's what I am trying:

```
def create_message(sender, to, cc, bcc, subject, message_text, file=None, thread=None):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    print(thread)
    message['to'] = to
    if cc:
        message['cc'] = cc
    if bcc:
        message['bcc'] = bcc
    if thread:
        message['threadId'] = thread
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    msg = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
    message.attach(msg)
    if file:
        message = attach_file(message, file)
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}
```

But it isn't working. I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. The `threadId` needed to be moved from the `message` dictionary into the `output` itself.

Hopefully this clears it up for someone else:

```
def create_message(sender, to, cc, bcc, subject, message_text, file=None, thread=None):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to
    if cc:
        message['cc'] = cc
    if bcc:
        message['bcc'] = bcc
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    msg = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
    message.attach(msg)
    if file:
        message = attach_file(message, file)
    output =  {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}
    if thread:
        output['threadId'] = thread
    return output
```

Comment: Didn't work in my case, it still hits a new thread. Just confirm me two things... 1. How did you manage to get threadId in real time? (Like searching the `threadid` by subject line or something similar) and 2. Which function did you execute after returning the output?

Comment: This assumes you have the threadId when you execute the function.. The threadId is included in the information sent with the message you get from the API. I don't think there is a way to have the API decide which thread you are replying to, you have to tell it that.

As for the output, the next step is to create a draft. See the example under the Python tab in the docs: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts

Comment: If anyone is still confused, the `message_id` that you have to include when creating the reply email is NOT `message['id']`, but instead (and quite confusingly IMHO) it's `header['value']`, where `header` is the unique header in `message['headers']` whose `header['name']` is 'Message-ID'.

And the two are very much not the same. Oops

Comment: with this the message is grouped in the sender thread but not the receiver

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for this solution for so long thank you. What helped was just adding the threadId to the message about to be sent. This is how I solved it.

```python
def send_message(
        from_sender: str,
        to: str,
        subject: str,
        message_text: str,
        file: str = None,
        thread_id: str = None,
    ):
        """Send an new email message
        Args:
            from_sender: Email address of the sender.
            to: Email address of the receiver.
            subject: The subject of the email message.
            message_text: The text of the email message.
            file: The filename of the attachment.
            thread_id: The id of the thread if you want to reply to it.
        Returns:
            Message
        """
        try:
            message = EmailMessage()
            message.set_content(message_text)
            message["to"] = to
            message["from"] = from_sender
            message["subject"] = subject
            if file:
                # guessing the MIME type
                type_subtype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(file)
                maintype, subtype = type_subtype.split("/")
                with open(file, "rb") as fp:
                    attachment_data = fp.read()
                message.add_attachment(attachment_data, maintype, subtype)
            encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()
            created_message = {"raw": encoded_message}
            if thread_id:
                created_message["threadId"] = thread_id
            sent_message = Message(
                **(
                    service()
                    .users()
                    .messages()
                    .send(userId="me", body=created_message)
                    .execute()
                )
            )
            return sent_message
        except HttpError as error:
            print("An error occurred:", error)
```